# Change Version number and build in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode5

I have upgraded my Xcode to Xcode 5. From where can I change the version and build number which are now not visible in Target Summary?

[image]

Comment: Left pane - > select project name -> General

Comment: Libraries don't have build/version numbers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Select your project on the left. Then under target, select the target.

Note it's in the General tab.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In the screenshot you posted your target is a library, which do not have the build/version number.

Select your target and then go to the `General` tab. 
Then `Identity` you can change the Version ad the build

Or open the `Info` tab and then `Custom iOS Target Properties`, here your can change the build and version number.

Answer (score 4):

In left pane select project name - > select target -> General choose version and Build.
make sure target is selected , if project setting is selected you won't able to see desired options

[image: General]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I type anything into the build field, it replaces it with 1.0.2. If I go to the Info tab, I can change it there, but it doesn't remember the setting if I leave the info tab.

Comment: I think you need to change the project settings as well, currently you are changing target settings only.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your target, there you can modify them:

- in General: under Identity: under your Bundel identifier: version and build
- in Info: under Custom iOS Target Properties: Bundel version

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out a new tool I've been developing called Xcodebump. It can handle updating both CFBundleShortVersionString and CFBundleVersion. As a final step it will also checkin to git and tag the commit to match up with those CFBundle values.

The [Xcodebump project](https://github.com/markeissler/Xcodebump) is located here:

https://github.com/markeissler/Xcodebump

I developed Xcodebump because agvtool has become a bit crusty and this topic comes up on Stackoverflow quite often.